# Regex in javascript - HTML parsing

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some advice in the subject of regular expressions in js.

I have a string

```
var page = '<html attribute1="<test1>" test2 attribute2="test2"></html>';
```

I'm trying to get fragment

```
<html attribute1="<test1>" test2 attribute2="test2">
```

But my code:

```
page.match(/<.*?>/);
```

returns only chars to first occurrence of ">", therefore

```
<html attribute1="<test1>
```

What should I do to ignore the symbols ">" appearing between quotes? Please help me and sorry for my English ;)

Comment: Parsing things like that requires a more powerful parsing mechanism than that afforded by regular expressions. You can concoct hacks to deal with restricted cases, but your example here is a good one to illustrate the difficulty.

Comment: refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Browser manufacturers spend months coding query selectors, DOM traversal, data attributes, and countless other features...and this is how people choose to design things, instead? *sigh*

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to solve here? Why do you need this `html` tag? What's the bigger issue being tackled?

Comment: why are there angle brackets in the attrib? that ain't right...

Answer (score 0):

You might try this regex:

```
^<(?:"[^"]*"|[^>])+>
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iY8yY1).

Which will match either double quotes and anything inside or non `>` till the first `>`.

And maybe use this one if you also have single quotes:

```
^<(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])+>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `page.match(/<.*">/);`

Answer (score 0):

`page.match(/\<.*\>(?=<\/)/);` should do the trick.

The pattern you're using is picking up on `.*?` as a lazy match and ending after finding the first instance of `>`. Removing the `?` from the pattern turns it into a greedy match, continuing the search until the final `>` and returning the full string.

I've also added a lookahead to end the match before the closing html tag and added backslashes to escape symbols.